# How to retrieve data from MySql table and send to client side in streaming mode via ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, http

I am facing a situation where I have to fetch and show around 200,000 rows from a MySql table to html. Now the issue is it is taking a lot of time if I fetch all rows and send it to client via ajax.

But I am thinking to fetch data in streaming mode from MySql table and also send that to client in streaming mode.

Is it possible at all to fetch and send data in streaming mode?

If it is can you please give me a start point from where to start?

Consider my ajax as;

```
  $.ajax({

       url:"myurl.com",

       method:"post",

       data:jsonData,

       success:function(data){

            console.log(data);
       }
  })
```

And the php is like;

```
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $result=$conn->query("select * from tableName");

  $ret=Array();
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               array_push($ret,$row);  
      }
  } 
  else {
      echo "0 results";
  } 

  echo json_encode($ret);
```

Upto this I have done, but what are the changes are necessary to do the stuffs in streaming mode.

Comment: where is the query?

Comment: query is like `select * from tablename`, still added in question

Comment: Well, it looks like the first thing to do would be to limit the size of returned dataset. The query can be modified as `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 50`. Now, to fetch the remaining records (in small chunks), think a tutorial such as [this](http://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database) could be useful in summarising the implementation strategy.

Comment: Ok, that I understand and I can do that very easily, but in this case I am creating a http connection(ajax call) for each page. But is it possible in single connection I 'll get data in streaming way?

Answer (score 0):

If your intend is to send multiple requests over a single connection, then you need to look into HTTP/2 or HTTP/3. These allow for one connection to be used back and forth i.e. the client connects and you get a two way connection where you can send and receive *any number* of requests. More specifically, you can send one request to *register* with your server then your server can send as much data as it wants *forever*. This is how most modern websites are implemented. Those where you change one thing in one browser and it auto-updates in another... that's HTTP/2 (TCP) or HTTP/3 (UDP).

With HTTP/1.1, you need to use one request with all the queries you need and then your server can send all the replies one after the other. Say you are replying with JSON data, you could write one JSON object per line. If you want to use the [streaming feature of HTTP/1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), it's doable, but not very useful unless the reply is fairly large (like over 64Kb).